# Template type deduction of template class with template member

Tags: c++, templates

Lets say I have following (rather confusing example from Bjarne Stroustrup's book) template class with template member

```
template<class Scalar> class complex {
    Scalar re, im;
public:
        template<class T>
        complex(const complex<T> &c) : re(c.re), im(c.im) {}
        //...
}
```

1. `complex<float> cf(0,0);` is one way to create object of this class, but is `Scalar` deduced as float or `T` is deduced as float in this example? What are some different ways to create objects of this class? I want to understand how template type is being deduced from these examples.
2. What is the use of member templates?

Comment: That's not the constructor that will be called for `complex<float> cf(0,0);`

Comment: If Scalar is e.g. float for the original and double for the copy, this is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `complex<float> cf(0,0);` is one way to create object of this class, but is `Scalar` deduced as `float` or `T` is deduced as `float` in this example? What are some different ways to create objects of this class? I want to understand how template type is being deduced from these examples.

In this example, nothing is deduced. `Scalar` is explicitly specified as `float`.

The template constructor does not get called for this.

> What is the use of member templates?

Say you have:

```
Complex<float> c1(10, 20);
```

and then you want to use `c1` to create another `Complex` but with a different type for `Scalar`.

```
Complex<double> c2(c1);
```

In this case the template constructor is used. `Scalar` is explicitly specified as `double` and `T` is deduced as `float`.

Comment: implicit type conversion `double` to `float` wouldn't happen if there was no copy constructor, correct?

Comment: @NulledPointer Are you calling the template constructor a copy constructor? In that case, you are right. Otherwise, I don't understand your question.

Comment: It should be called a 'template copy constructor' IMO

Comment: @NulledPointer, you could try popularizing the term. Who knows? Maybe in a few years down the line, it will be an accepted term.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class Outer>
struct S1 {
    template<class Inner>
    S1(const S1<Outer>& rhs) {}
};

template<class Outer>
struct S2 {
    template<class Inner>
    S2(const S2<Inner>& rhs) {}
};

S1<float> s1f;
S2<float> s2f;

S1<double> s1d(s1f); // error
S2<double> s2d(s2f); // ok
```

What's being demonstrated is deduction of a member function template parameter from the template type of a parameter.

For `s2d` above, we know that `Outer` is double, it's specified not deduced.

However when we pass `s2f` to its constructor we are passing an object of type S2. We provide a constructor that takes `S2<? Inner ?>`, so we have a container match if we deduce `Inner` to be float.

What's being demonstrated is a templated class with further templated member functions. Consider:

```
template<class Outer>
struct S {
    template<class Other>
    S(const Other& rhs) {}
};
```

If we do

```
S<float> sf;
S<int> si(sf);
```

Here the copy constructor deduces `Inner` to be not just `int` but `S<int>`.

Practical use:

```
template<class C, class T>
struct PtrContainer {
    using container_type = C;
    using value_type = T;
    using self_type = PtrContainer<container_type, value_type>;
    using ptr_type = T*;
    using size = sizeof(T);

    PtrContainer() : c() {}

    void append(ptr_type p) {
        c.push_back(p);
    }

    template<class D>
    std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T, D>::value, void>::type
    transfer(PtrContainer<D>& rhs) {
        c.insert(c.end(), rhs.c.begin(), rhs.c.end());
        rhs.c.clear();
    }

    void clear() {
        for (auto* ptr: c) {
            delete ptr;
        }
        c.clear();
    }

    ~PtrContainer() { clear(); }

    container_type<ptr_type> c;
};

struct S {};
struct SD : public S {};

int main() {
    PtrContainer<vector, S> pvs;
    pvs.append(new S);
    PtrContainer<list, SD> plsd;
    plsd.append(new SD);
    pcs.transfer(plsd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the code explicitly specifies `Scalar` to be `float` (no deduction happens). But the copy(ish) constructor you show is not the one that will be called in your subsequent example.

Comment: This was better suited as a comment, its not a complete answer